# Django, store internal link in database

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I want to save the internal URL (you can see in the picture below, the last input), and then access it from the code, so I will be able to change it from the admin panel, but it shows error like in image 2

[image]

[image]

Comment: what is this image ? from where did you get it ?

Comment: which one? , first is from Django admin panel, the second one is error message after I click link in menu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you save `django template` of your url and not an `url` itself:

```
{% url 'main-page' %}  # this is template

/main-page/  # this is relative url
```

in your case you can simply save the relative part of url. or you should before use 'url' in render made render_to_string.
more here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/templates/#django.template.loader.render_to_string